# Iterate through and decode Dot11Elt layers -- Scapy

Tags: sniffer, packet, 802.1x

**OBJECTIVE**

I want to iterate through the Dot11Elt layers of a beacon frame that I captured with Scapy. I also want to decode the `.info` of each `ID` layer.

```
def packet_handler(packet) :

    if packet.haslayer(Dot11) :
        if packet.subtype == 8 :
            for i in packet.getlayer(Dot11Elt) :
                print i.info

def main() :

    sniff(count = 50, prn = packet_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

**RESULTS**

This is only giving me the info of `ID = 0` which is the `SSID`

I want to be able to iterate through the layers to get to `ID = 1` , `ID = 3` and so forth.

Also, I have no idea what this type of encoding it is that I get when I print

- `packet.getlayer(Dot11Elt)`
- `packet(Dot11Elt)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the info in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29989032, you need to iterate over them like this:

```
dot11elt = packet.getlayer(Dot11Elt)
while dot11elt:
     print dot11elt.ID, dot11elt.info
     dot11elt = dot11elt.payload.getlayer(Dot11Elt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy. you can have whatever you want

```
 from netaddr.core import NotRegisteredError
 from netaddr import *
 from scapy.all import *
 import logging  
 import logging.handlers

 PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE=0
 PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE=4

 WHITELIST =   ['18:dc:56:f0:40:40','34:a3:95:b1:2b:d9','48:13:7e:57:ae:b6','98:0c:a5:17:7d:2d'] 
 my_logger = logging.getLogger('agentlogger')
 handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('tplink3022.log',    mode='a', maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=10, encoding=None, delay=0)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)

def PacketHandler(pkt):
if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):

    if pkt.type==PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype ==      PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE:
        PrintPacket(pkt)
def mac_info(mac):
    global macf
    maco = EUI(mac)
    try:
        macf = maco.oui.registration().org
    except NotRegisteredError:
        macf = "Not available"
    return macf
def PrintPacket(pkt):
    print "Probe Request Captured:"
    try:
        extra = pkt.notdecoded
    except:
        extra = None
    if extra!=None:
        signal_strength = -(256-ord(extra[-4:-3]))
    else:
        signal_strength = -100
        print "No signal strength found"    
    mac_info(pkt.addr2)
    print "Time: %s   Source: %s SSID: %s MANF: %s RSSi: %d"%(pkt.time,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,macf,signal_strength)

    str = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d\n"%(pkt.time,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,macf,signal_strength)
WriteToFile(str)

def WriteToFile(str):
    my_logger.warn(str)

def main():
    from datetime import datetime
    print "[%s] Starting scan"%datetime.now()
    print "Scanning :"
    try:
        sniff(iface=sys.argv[1],prn=PacketHandler,count=0,store=0)
    except:
          print'[!] Eroor : Failed to initialize sniffing'    


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()`
```

Comment: I don't know if it answers the question, but for sure the indentation is broken.